# Tricky Triple Sql Join While finding the most recent date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group, database-administration

I apologize if this question has been asked in a similar way before.  I am rather new to SQL and am having a very difficult time finding the solution to my problem.  Very confused.

I currently have three tables:

---

Templates - | id | name |

---

Users - | id | full_name |

---

Changelog - | id | id_user | id_template | last_edited_at

---

I have a table filled with templates.

I have a separate table full of users WHO make changes on those templates.  Every time a change is made, an entry is created in the changelog table.

I am trying to create a query with the main goal being fetching EVERY record from templates, as well as WHEN it was most recently changed, and BY WHOM.

I came up with this query which allows me to find the most recent change for a specific template ID.

```
SELECT changelogs.id_user, changelogs.updated_at, users.full_name
FROM changelogs
JOIN users
ON changelogs.id_user = users.id
WHERE changelogs.id_template = :templateId
ORDER BY changelogs.updated_at DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

I orignally tried to solve this problem by looping through each template record, and running the above query for each record ID, but that is slow and doesn't work.  I know there must be a way to do this in SQL, and I wanted to see if anybody has solved a similar problem.  I didn't design this database, so sorry if it is not optimized.

My ideal final result would be a table that looks like:

---

| template.id | template.name | user.name | changelog.updated_at |

Thanks so much in advance for any guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two JOINs to get the information from all the tables and then use a [SUBQUERY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html) to get the maximum value for the updated_at field, like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.id as template_id, t.name as template_name, 
    u.name as user_name, 
    c.updated_at as changelog_updated_at 
FROM 
    changelogs c

INNER JOIN templates t on c.id_template = t.id
INNER JOIN users u on c.id_user = u.id

WHERE 
  c.updated_at = 
    (SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM changelogs c2 where c2.id_template = t.id)

ORDER BY t.template_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT cl.id_user, cl.updated_at, u.full_name
FROM changelogs cl JOIN
     users u
     ON cl.id_user = u.id
WHERE cl.updated_at = (SELECT MAX(cl2.updated_at)
                       FROM changelogs cl2
                       WHERE cl2.id_template = cl.templateId
                      );
```

For each template referred to in the outer query the subquery finds the maximum update date.  This is then used to filter the records in the outer query.

Comment: Wasn't me, only thing I noticed with this solution is that a template that was never changed isn't included. If the creation isn't included in the ChangeLog table.

Comment: @EdCallahan . . . Doesn't seem likely because the accepted answer also assumes that all templates are in the changelog.

Comment: I just noticed I was down-voted too. Whatever, how do you down-vote the use of a window function? They are simply cool. ;)

Comment: @EdCallahan is there anyway to run that window function (with row_number) or similar in MySQL, I can't get your query to run and I would like to set up a query that also includes templates that haven't been changed for another part of my project

Answer (score 0):

I think a window function is your friend here. I didn't spin up sample tables to run this on, so there my be a type-o or two:

```
select *
from (

    select *
        ,row_number() over (partition by t.id order by c.last_edited_at desc) row
        from Templates t
        left join ChangeLog c
        on t.id=c.id_template
        left join Users u
        on c.id_user=u.id

) t
where row=1
```